# How to overloading comparison operator with pointer class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Here is my code, but it doesn't work.

How can I overload the comparison operator for my pointer class?

```
using namespace std;

class x{

public:
    int y = 0;
    bool operator < (const x* b) const{
        cout << "inline";
        return (y < b->y);
    }
};

int main(){
    x *q = new x;
    q->y = 10;
    x *w = new x;
    w->y = 0;

    if (q < w){
        cout << "false" <<endl;
    }else{
        cout << "true" << endl;
    }

    // Cleanup:
    delete q;
    delete w;
}
```

and here's my result

```
false
```

Comment: why are there any pointers in your code in the first place? You should not use `new` to create objects

Comment: @idclev463035818 This is completely not true, c++ has pointers for a reason, if they were not to be used they would remove them

Comment: @dimoraichev what exactly is "completely not true" ? This is not true: "if they were not to be used they would remove them" because what is considered good practice and idioms change over time, but C++ cannot simply remove old stuff because it has to be backwards compatible. Anyhow using raw pointers has its place, but not in code like this. OPs code leaks memory and this could be avoided easily by not using raw owning pointers

Comment: @idclev463035818 It is true that the code leaks memory, this would have been constructive, but saying that the person asking should not use them is not. This to me looks like the asker is trying to learn about raw pointers, which in my opinion could be very useful for understanding how memory works. Anyway as you said raw pointers have their place and new developers need to learn how to use them

Comment: @dimoraichev I stand by what I wrote. The most important thing a beginner needs to learn about raw pointers is: Dont use them. The leak can only be fixed in a proper way by not using raw pointers. Note that manual `delete` is definitely **not** the right fix, because it is not exception safe.

Answer (score 4):

No idea what you are trying to do but this will 'work'

```
if (*q < w){
    cout << "false" <<endl;
}else{
    cout << "true" << endl;
}
```

Comparison operators for pointers are built into C++, you cannot overload them. At least one operand for an overloaded operator must be a class type (or struct type etc). And class type means class type not pointer to class type.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compares 2 pointers (& ignores your operator). See 2 cases:

**Case 1: q > w**

[image]

**Case 2: q < w**

[image]

--

In order to use your operator, you have to fix to this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class x {

public:
    int y = 0;

    const bool operator < (const x* p) const { // Compare object vs pointer
        return y < p->y;
    }
};

int main() {
    x* q = new x;
    q->y = 10;
    x* w = new x;
    w->y = 0;

    if (*q < w) { // Fix: Compare object vs pointer
        cout << "false" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "true" << endl;
    }

    delete q;
    delete w;
}
```

--

Unless you have a special need to use `new`, I prefer:

```
#include <iostream>

class x {

public:
    int y = 0;

    const bool operator < (const x& r) const { // Compare 2 objects
        return y < r.y;
    }
};

int main() {
    x q;
    q.y = 10;

    x w;
    w.y = 0;

    if (q < w) {
        std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    }
}
```